# Spring Boot Test - Mocking A Handler Bean That Is Placed Deep In The Chain Of Responsibility

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito

This should happen quite often:

`RestController -> SomeClass -> SomeOtherClass -> YetAnotherClass` and so on...

In my specific case there is a chain of responsibility which is injected to a rest controller. Each class is injected to it's previous class in the above chain.

I have implemented this with spring boot and I'm trying to test the REST resource. I want to Mock the **"YetAnotherClass"** so that when I send a request with MockMvc I can verify that something has happened in the mock object.

The problem is if I use **@MockBean** to mock **YetAnotherClass** then I have to inject it to **SomeOtherClass**. I have tried to inject it with **@TestConfiguration** but it seems that the Mock object injection doesn't work this way when the request is sent through MockMvc and the mock object is nested deep inside a chain such as above. (The original bean is injected not the mock one)

I know that JMockit mocks every instance of a class so it would solve my problem. But Spring boot defaults to Mockito and I prefer to avoid inconsistencies.

How can I implement such a test scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into a lot of annoyance using `Mockito`'s annotation config setup when setting up `Spring JUnit` text fixtures.

I've found the way I like mocking beans with external integrations like this this by essentially having a separate `MockObjectsConfig` class with the mock objects I want using the standard Spring Context Configuration, and then import it alongside my real test config:

```
@Configuration
public class MockObjectsConfig {

    @Bean
    public YetAnotherClass yetAnotherClass() {
        Mockito.mock(YetAnotherClass.class); // and add any thenReturns, answers, etc. here
    }

    ... More mock beans...

}
```

Then include it in your test like so:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyRealConfigClass.class, MockObjectsConfig.class)
public class MyJunitTest {

    @Autowired
    private RestController restController;

}
```

You can also annotate your mock bean with `@Profile` and test with `@ActiveProfiles` if you need to prevent a conflict there.

This way your mock `YetAnotherClass` will get injected into your context like all your other beans -- no relying on, mixing, and fiddling around with Mockito and other library annotations.

Comment: Thank you. Seems like a good idea. Will give it a try and accept when the test gets green.

Comment: Sure, happy to help if you have more questions

Comment: @Dovmo What if you what to change the thenReturns for YetAnotherClass inside a test in MyJunitTest?
Is it possible even? 

I'm curious how people handle these situations